# If $x(t)$ be a known trajectory does the $x(-t)$ represent the retracing trajectory?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, time-reversal-symmetry

### Assertion

If there is time-reversal invariance, Newton's law (for a system described by one generalized coordinate $q$) $$m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}q(t)=F\Big(q(t)\Big)\tag{a}$$ implies that if $q(t)$ is a solution, $q(-t)$ is also a solution i.e., $$m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}q(-t)=F\Big(q(-t)\Big)\tag{a1}$$ The operational implementation of time-reversal $t\to -t$ requires doing the following: $$q\to q,~~\text{and}~~\dot{q}\to -\dot{q}\tag{b}$$ to the instantaneous values of $q$ and $\dot{q}$ by which the system is made to retrace the path.

### A concrete example

Suppose a harmonic oscillator starts from right extreme position A with initial conditions $x=a$ and $\dot{x}=0$ at $t=0$. Therefore, its trajectory is given by $$x(t)=a\cos\omega t.\tag{1}$$ It reaches the mean position B at time $t=T/4$ at which $x=0$ and $\dot{x}=-a\omega$. Now the prescrition of the time-reversal (Eq. (b)) requires that at $t=T/4$, we set $x=0$ and $\dot{x}=+a\omega$, and verify whether the trajectory is retraced. It's easy to check that with these as the initial conditions, the solution becomes $$x(t)=-a\cos\omega t\tag{2}$$ which indeed represents the retracing path BA traversed from B to A i.e., the trajectory (2) is opposite to the trajectory described by (1).

$\bullet$ However, note that the retracing trajectory (2) cannot be obtained from trajectory (1) by simply sending $t\to -t$, and therefore, I have the following question.

### Question

*If $x(t)$ represents a continuous trajectory AB traversed in the direction from A to B, which trajectory should $x(-t)$ be identified with? From my example, it appears that $x(-t)$ is not the retracing trajectory.*

Comment: Are you looking for a word? Something like 'backward', or 'bounced', or 'reversed', or 'inverted [time]'?

Comment: @Keepthesemind I don't understand your question. If there is time-reversal invariance of N. Law, and if $x(t)$ be a solution, $x(-t)$ is also a solution. This is a provable fact. I'm asking which trajectory does $x(-t)$ correspond to. It's not a terminology question.

Comment: Reversing t amounts to the same thing as inverting qdot. So, that would be a perfect bounce against a perpendicular surface.

Comment: @Keepthesemind That's not the question. In my example, $x(t)$ of Eq. (1) describes the forward solution where the trajectory is traversed from A to B. And in Eq.(2) $x(t)$ describes the time-reversed solution where the trajectory is traversed from B to A. But you can't obtain (2) from (1) by changing the argument $t$ in (1) to $-t$. This implies $x(-t)$ is *not* the retracing trajectory. Then what is $x(-t)$?

Comment: (2) is the time-reversed trajectory of (1).

Comment: $x(-t)$ is a valid solution.  No one said that it has to bear a physical relationship to $x(t)$.   I'm not sure what you are looking for, if not a word to describe $x(-t)$.

Comment: @garyp Don't you agree that the retracing solution is the time-reversed solution?

Comment: Yes.  But look at your first paragraph.  "if q(t) is a solution, q(−t) is also a solution".  Perhaps the difficulty is this:  "time reversal" in the sense of repeating the path requires  $q(t)\rightarrow q(t)$ and $\dot{q}(t)\rightarrow -\dot{q}(t)$ which is different that the formal replacement of variables which merely shows that $q\rightarrow q$ and $\dot{q}\rightarrow -\dot{q}$ is a solution.

Comment: I don't think equation $(2)$ is correct. Consider equation $(1)$. Graph it and take a look at the interval from $[0, T/4]$. Now if equation $(2)$ is correct, plugging in say $T/8$ should at least give something positive for a true retracing but it doesn't

Comment: @DWade64 For retracing you're supposed to substitute a value between $T/4$ and $T/2$. Not $T/8$.

Comment: You can retrace any part of the curve. I'm just focusing on the section from $[0, T/4]$. If you want to retrace the function $x(t) = a\cos(\omega t)$ over $[0,T/4]$, the easiest way would just be to use  the same function but over the interval $[T/4,0]$. That is, time flows backwards. Another way (which works for any parametric curve):  Use the reflection $x(-t) = a\cos(\omega (-t)) = a\cos(\omega t)$ but over the interval $[-T/4, -0] = [-T/4, 0]$. This function has horizontal reflection (left/right) symmetry. But to give

Comment: another example. Consider $e^t$ over the interval $[-2,1]$. You can get the backtrack retracing with the same function over $[1,-2]$. Or you could use the left/right reflection $e^{-t}$ over the interval $[-(1),-(-2)] = [-1,2]$

Comment: Okay I see what you did. With those intervals it makes sense

Comment: First you need to precisely  define what *you* mean by "time reversal".  Do you want the same equation in transformed coordinates to apply ?  Do you mean you want $m\frac{d^2}{d(-t)^2}q((-t))=F\Big(q((-t))\Big)$ ?

Comment: @StephenG Given Eq.(a) is true, you can show that $q(−t)$ satisfies Eq. (a1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a semantics question.

- $x(-t)$ is the time reversed trajectory of $x(t)$. Physically, for $t > 0$, you can imagine this trajectory as that of a particle that starts moving at negative $t$, then is time reversed (intuitively, 'hits a mirror') at $t = 0$.
- the trajectory that "reverses the path" of $x(t)$ by time reversal at time $t_0$ is $x(-t + 2 t_0)$. Note that whenever we talk about "time reversal" alone, we always mean time reversal at time $t = 0$.
- if time reversal symmetry holds and $x(t)$ is a solution, $x(-t)$ is a solution
- if time reversal symmetry *and* time translational symmetry hold, and $x(t)$ is a solution, then the "reversed path" $x(-t + 2 t_0)$ is a solution

Most of the time, when time reversal symmetry is present, time translational symmetry is also present, so we don't bother to distinguish these two concepts.

On the other hand, consider a particle in the electric field $E(t) = E_0 (t /t_0)^2$. This electric field obeys time reversal symmetry (about the time $t = 0$, as by convention) but it breaks time translational symmetry. Therefore, if $x(t)$ is a solution, so is $x(-t)$, but $x(-t + 2 t_0)$ is not, as you can check.

Comment: "_the trajectory that "reverses the path" of $x(t)$ by time reversal at time $t_0$ is $x(-t + 2 t_0)$._" This appears to be correct when I apply it to my example. But I have no clue how did you conclude this? How did you know that you have to change the argument from $t\to -t+2t_0$ and not $t\to -t+t_0$, for example? (2)If I understand you correct, for $x(-t)$ to be the time-reversed path of $x(t)$, one must do the time-reversal at $t=0$. Is that correct? @knzhou

Comment: (1) If you’re confused about this, try drawing a graph. (2) Yes.

Comment: I do not understand this retracing bit. A rocket decribes a trajectory. It cannot be retraced as energy conservations does not allow it. It has to start from an x0, t0 and end at infinity, if there are no energy losses. It cannot come back from infinity. There could be an equivalent projectile from infinity ending up in an explosion on the rocket location,  to dicipate the energy. S0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the physics, but I can speak a little bit about the math. This is an exercise in *function transformations*: Vertical shifts, Vertical scaling/reflecting, Horizontal shifts, and Horizontal scaling/reflecting.

$f(x) + 10$ would be a vertical shift, $-2f(x)$ would be a vertical stretch + a vertical reflection or vice versa, and $f(-x)$ is a horizontal (left/right) reflection of the graph across the y-axis.

So imagine a graph of $x(t)$. You start your pen at negative infinity and draw some curve all the way to positive infinity. Now $x(-t)$ is mathematically speaking, just the left/right reflection across the y-axis. Therefore all *outputs* that happened after $t = 0$ suddenly get swapped to the negative side of the time axis. That is, everything that happens last suddenly happens first. And everything that happened first (on the negative side of $t$) now happens last after you do the reflection. While $x(t)$ traces out some path from the beginning of time to the end of time. $x(-t)$ would trace out the exact same path, but in reverse (it plots out positions of $x(t)$ in reverse).

So now imagine starting your pen at negative infinity. You draw some $x(t)$ curve all the way up to $t = 0$ and stop. If you want the reflected graph on the other side of $t = 0$ just make $x(-t)$ on the other side. Therefore as you start moving the pen again from $t = 0$ onward to infinity, you just retrace everything you did in reverse. Now let's look at another answer to this question. Say you start the pen at negative infinity and draw some $x(t)$ curve all the way to $t = t_0$. And let's assume $t_0$ is some positive number (we don't have to, as it's a variable. But let's do it anyways). You stop your pen at $t_0$. From $t_0$ onward, you want the backtrack. Therefore, you need the reflected graph of $x(t)$ across the line $t = t_0$. So you say, hmmmm. What if I make the reflected graph across the y-axis $x(-t)$? But then you realize you need to push the graph to the right by $2t_0$. This is a *combination* of function transformation. Combining 2 horizontal transformations is a little harder than 2 vertical transformation. But nonetheless, the graph on the right side of $t = t_0$ will be $x(-(t - 2t_0))$ or $x(-t + 2t_0)$, which is the knzhou's response.